# Number of ways constructing a $k$-clique.

Tags: graph-theory

I have a complete graph $A=K_{n}$ and a natural numbers $m,k$

> Determine the number of all subgraphs in $A$ that have exactly $m$ edges and at least one $k$-clique. The same with subgraphs that don't contain any $k$-clique. Let's denote these numbers respectively as $A(m),B(m)$

I would like to focus on following case:

$${n\choose 2}\ge m \ge 0$$

Is this true that $$A(m)+B(m)={{n\choose 2}\choose m}$$?

Comment: Yes I think it is, since $A(m)+B(m)=$ number of subgraphs with $m$ edges. Is that all your question? Or you want an answer for the first part also?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you( or someone else) answer for the first part.

Comment: I assume that the vertices are distinguishable. Let us first choose $k$ vertices for the clique. We can do this in $n \choose k$ ways. We know that the clique has $ h = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ edges, so we are left with $m - h$ edges to choose arbitrarily. The number of all edges is $l = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. So from $l - h$ edges we choose $m - h$. Therefore the answer should be ${n \choose k} \cdot {{l -h} \choose {m - h}}$

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of all subgraphs in $A$ that have exactly $m$ edges and at least one $k$-clique is complimentary to the number of subgraphs that have exactly $m$ edges and don't contain any $k$-clique, $A(m) + B(m)$ is just the number of all subgraphs with $m$ edges. So choose $m$ edges from $n \choose 2$ edges: $$A(m) + B(m) = {{n\choose 2}\choose m}.$$
In the comments it was shown that the number of all subgraphs in $A$ that have exactly $m$ edges and at least one $k$-clique is $$ {n \choose k} \cdot {{{n \choose 2} - {k \choose 2}} \choose {m - {k \choose 2}}}. $$
Therefore the number of subgraphs that have exactly $m$ edges and don't contain any $k$-clique is
$$ {{n\choose 2}\choose m} - {n \choose k} \cdot {{{n \choose 2} - {k \choose 2}} \choose {m - {k \choose 2}}}.$$

---

For completeness, I just repeat the proof from the comments (due to [NikoWielopolski](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/704328/nikowielopolski)) showing how to calculate the number of all subgraphs in $A$ that have exactly $m$ edges and at least one $k$-clique.

Start by selecting $k$ vertices from $A$ (together with all edges between these vertices - this will then be a $k$-clique) - to do this we choose $k$ vertices from $n$: so there are $n \choose k$ ways to do this. The $k$-clique has $k \choose 2$ edges, so we need to add $m - {k \choose 2}$ edges outside of the clique to complete the subgraph. The total amount of edges outside of the $k$-clique we have chosen is ${n \choose 2} - {k \choose 2}$, so there are $${{{n \choose 2} - {k \choose 2}} \choose {m - {k \choose 2}}}$$ ways to do this.

Combining the choice of vertices for the $k$-clique with the choice of edges outside the clique yields the total number of subgraphs with exactly $m$ edges and at least one $k$-clique: $$ {n \choose k} \cdot {{{n \choose 2} - {k \choose 2}} \choose {m - {k \choose 2}}}. $$